# Grant Rights to docker_engine pipe

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I am trying to *grant access to my account* on *docker_engine service*. Here is a reference link - https://github.com/tfenster/dockeraccesshelper

```
$account="<DOMAIN>\<USERNAME>"
$npipe = "\\.\pipe\docker_engine"                                                                                 
$dInfo = New-Object "System.IO.DirectoryInfo" -ArgumentList $npipe                                               
**$dSec = $dInfo.GetAccessControl()**                                                                                 
$fullControl =[System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::FullControl                                       
$allow =[System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow                                                  
$rule = New-Object "System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule" -ArgumentList $account,$fullControl,$allow
$dSec.AddAccessRule($rule)                                                                                        
$dInfo.SetAccessControl($dSec)
```

But this fails when on bolded code. Here is error that I see,

```
Exception calling "GetAccessControl" with "1" argument(s): "\\.\pipe\docker_engine"
At line:1 char:1
+ [System.IO.Directory]::GetAccessControl(“\\.\pipe\docker_engine”)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirectoryNotFoundException
```

I confirmed that Docker service is running. Also when I run `docker verison` , it shows result with an error at the end -

```
Client:
 Version:           24.0.4
 API version:       1.43
 Go version:        go1.20.5
 Git commit:        3713ee1
 Built:             Fri Jul  7 14:52:09 2023
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Context:           default
error during connect: in the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run with elevated privileges to connect: Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/version": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I find this suspicious.